# Query issue using AS in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a complex query getting summations from several fields and all seem to work fine except for one sub select (there are several). I have a WHERE clause that uses table1.field = table2.field AND CONVERT(DATE, date/time field) BETWEEN 'firstDate' AND 'lastDate' AS total. It works fine without the 'AS total' but when I run it with the 'AS total included my result does not go into 'total'. Not sure why I get a result one way but not the other. I am getting a DBNull exception for 'total' in VS since the AS seems to not get the value returned.

This a SQL Sever database.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, a.intime, a.outtime)) 
FROM 
    table1 a, table2 a b
WHERE 
    a.empKey = b.employeeKey 
    AND CONVERT(DATE, outtime) BETWEEN '2018/07/12 4:00 AM' AND '2018/07/12 5:00 PM' AS total
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Remove the a behind table2?

Comment: you can't use aliases in a where clause. Why would you want to? that value isn't returned in your query. It looks like you want `Total = SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, a.intime, a.outtime))`... in the `SELECT`, which is the same thing as `SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, a.intime, a.outtime)) as Total`

Comment: The a is not in the actual query. That was a typo that I obviously missed when I edited the query as I did not want to use the actual real data fields.

Comment: scsimon, the whole thing is enclosed in a sub select, so I believe the AS would be a part of that SELECT statement, right?

Comment: In that case, you are missing parentheses but you also have to have a column name for sub-queries. So you still need to alias the `SUM()...` Here's an example `select * from (select sum(1)) as total` will give the error *No column name was specified for column 1 of 'total'.*

Comment: Another Bad habit for you to avoid as well: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`!!!  It's been around for over 20 years.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, a.intime, a.outtime)) as total
FROM table1 a JOIN
     table2 b
     ON a.empKey = b.employeeKey 
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, outtime) BETWEEN '2018/07/12 4:00 AM' AND '2018/07/12 5:00 PM' ;
```

Comment: I tried incorporating your answer but now I get the error "total" does not belong to the table. I believe part of the issue is trying to to add to an already existing query that already contains several sub selects with sum(). However, this seemed to all work yesterday and not today and nothing has changed.

Comment: @guitarmaster . . .  `total` is only used here as a column alias.  This query cannot generate that error.